# using CSS reset in Joomla articles

Tags: css, joomla2.5, css-reset

I am a beginner to Joomla and the problem I recently faced is HTML tables having different looks in different browsers. I googled the issue and the found solution is to use a CSS reset. Now what I need to know is how to use CSS reset. Can I just copy and paste available CSS resets to my Joomla article or should I write my own?? I am confused a bit here. Your help would be appreciated !
Thanks all !!!

Comment: You would likely want to add this into the template for your site.

Comment: Actually I do not know where to put the css reset..

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe. You put the css reset before all the other styles that you define. If you have multiple files, put the reset at the top of the first one you include in your html file.

Answer (score 1):

I would even advise to do a CSS normalize instead of a CSS reset. A nice description of the advantages and disadvantages are given in [this article](http://the-pastry-box-project.net/oli-studholme/2013-june-3/).

Including a CSS normalize or reset is just a matter of including a separate CSS file as early as possible in the page (preferably in the head section).